# python win32com importing issue windows server 2012 r2

Tags: python-3.x, windows-server-2012-r2, win32com

So, I am trying to import win32com.client and when I am running the script in Windows Server 2012 using python 3.5 I get the next error :

`import win32api, sys, os
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

I've tried the next things:

-Copied the pywintypes35.dll and pythoncom35.dll to Python35\Lib\site-packages\win32 and win32com

-Run the Python35\Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py

-Copied the file from step 1 into an virtualenv

None of this seems to work. It is a problem with python 3.5 in Windows Server 2012?

Comment: If you open a Python shell and import win32api, you get that dll error? Dependency Walker might help identify specifically what dll u'd missing, you might be able to run it on python -m win32api.

Answer (score 0):

You likely installed incompatible  versions like Python 32bit but win32com 64bit.

Comment: I have installed the same versions on Windows 8.1 64bit and it worked :) In Windows Server 2012 R2 still not found a solution.